# We are four brothers and two sisters. Who is our father in his seventies?

Tags: wordplay

Q. What is our father's name, or rather our family name? Who is he?

The more of our (first) names you unlock, the closer you are to finding out my father's name. After all, we are all related somehow!

We'll briefly introduce ourselves, then.

---

Hi, I'm his 1st son:

> I blew up in anger when my friend said I stank, then I decided to vanish into thin air, not to be found again.

Hi, I'm his 2nd son:

```
I     am              invisible     here       but       built   a       :y
```

Hi, I'm his 3rd son:

> Fine and dandy to work so hard at the gym, but you guys need to take off your sweaty ING before getting on me on your way home.

Hi, I'm his 4th son:

> People need me and consume me, greedy ones seek and crave for me, but I may not, I might, I might.

Hi, I'm his 1st daughter:

> Just 'cause I look damn hot, don't you dare touch me! And don't even think about asking me out on a rainy day, 'cause I won't look good anymore... Not at all...

Hi, I'm his 2nd daughter:

> Be sure to drop in on me and use me when you are nearby. Don't just dump your better half on the street, ok? I'll be looking at her every move, or rather *non-move*, until you leave me.

Comment: hahaha I love your username! (For future peoples' reference in case he ever changes it, his name at the time is Con-gras-tue-les-chiens)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your last name is

> STATION

1st son is

> GAS (STATION) (@QuantumTwinkie)

2nd son is

> SPACE (STATION) (wolfram42)

3rd son is

> TRAIN (STATION) (training at the gym, get on the train home)

4th son is

> POWER (STATION) (wolfram42)

1st daughter is

> FIRE (STATION) (QuantumTwinkie)

2nd Daughter is

> PARKING (STATION) (wolfram42)

Comment: Con-gras-tue-les-chiens, from Japan! Literally, pardon my French! You're the 1st to have nailed their family name. Only one more left to go; his 2nd daughter is anxiously waiting for her name to be called out! :D

Comment: Thanks, though the credit for most of the first names goes to other answerers. Very nice riddle, very fun.

Comment: Hi. As for the 2nd daughter, please refer to my comment left elsewhere. Her name has unexpectedly turned out to be the most eluding answer for everyone.

Comment: I was almost certain that the father would have had the initials T.V. but it turns out that particular relative is already 90 years old.

Answer (score 12):

2nd son seems to be

> Space. The invisible characters are spaces, :y = colon y = colony. A space colony.

3rd son is

> Train, thanks [Pierre Cathé](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/68131/46723)

4th son seems to be

> Power. It is consumed (electricity), craved by the greedy, a synonym for might.

Second daughter might be

> Parking. Your car is your better half. Leaving your car at a parking station will have it under surveillance (and it won't move). It is also better than dumping your car on the street.

Last name is probably

> Station since it follows all of the words found. The "Seventies" clue is that there is 7 letters.

Comment: Updated second daughter's name

Comment: Excellent job for the 2nd daughter, as well as your logical appoach overall! Perhaps this longer term is less commonly used in English-speaking countries than in Japan.

Answer (score 8):

Last Name

> Station

1st Son

> Gas Station (@QuantumTwinkie)

2nd Son

> Space Station (@wolfram42)

3rd Son

> Train Station (@Pierre Cathé)

4th Son

> Power Station (@wolfram42)

1st Daughter

> Fire Station (@QuantumTwinkie)

2nd Daughter

> Weigh Station (Trucks drop in, dump trailer behind, can weigh the trailer whether moving or still)

Comment: So close, but no cigar! This is a case of an interesting coincidence by a different interpretation. Her real name is something more *presentable* and its term/concept is more widely known, even in non-English speaking countries. The parts in bold can be the key: "Be sure to drop in on me and **use me** when you are nearby. Don't just dump your **better half** on the street, ok? I'll be looking at her every move, or rather ***non-move***, **until you leave me**."

Comment: "move", "dump", "drop" -- you are referring to a bathroom or toilet (better half = defecation)? move = bowel movement. I just don't see how this has anything to do with a station. EDIT: A HAH! for the second daughter's name, replace "ei" with "as" and "gh" with "te" and I think you'll have the answer

Answer (score 5):

1 is

> Gas/wind

2 is

> Space from [Wolfram42](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68128/we-are-four-brothers-and-two-sisters-who-is-our-father-in-his-seventies/68132#68132)

3 is

> ?

4 is

> Land?

5 is

> Fire?

6 is

> Water maybe, with the use of the word "drop"?